# Is there a Lay-Mathematician explanation for the proof technique of Zhang's Theorem?

Tags: prime-numbers

I've heard there are elements of Sieve Theory and whatnot but no further 'outline' of how he proved the theorem.

Comment: See what you think of https://www.quantamagazine.org/yitang-zhang-proves-landmark-theorem-in-distribution-of-prime-numbers-20130519/

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vkMXdShDdtY

Comment: Have you had a look at those links, Joshua?

Comment: Are you still here, Joshua?

Comment: Yes, they don't seem to give much insight into my specific question

Comment: OK, how about https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/CurrentEventsArticle.pdf

Comment: At a higher level, http://blogs.ethz.ch/kowalski/2013/05/21/bounded-gaps-between-primes/ and the many works cited therein.

Comment: So, Joshua, are those any better?

Comment: Gone away again, Joshua?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.